# axios post request working in React Native ios but not in android

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I know there many answers regarding to this question but I can't seem to find one that works for me. I'm sending a post request to my server using axios but it does not work in android although it does in ios. I'm currently using server ip address (not localhost), and I'm also sending headers when request but it is still not going through the network request for android.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const SERVER_URL = 'http://serverip:3000';

export function signin({ username, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${SERVER_URL}/user/authenticate`, { username, password }, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('login response', response);
      dispatch({
        type: USER_AUTH,
      });
      AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token || '');
    })
    .catch((response) => console.log('user sign in err', response));
  };
}
```

[image]
Has anyone had similar issue like myself and know how to make this work?

Thank you,

Comment: are you sure it works on ios but not android? or is it the other way around

Comment: I'm sure it only works in ios, not android

Comment: strange, i thought ios would only allow connection to  https

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using 'https' for ios side, but my question is same code base is not working in android. I tried to run with different combinations (http, https) but none of them work and that's why I posted this question.

Comment: do you get any error/warning when working in android?

Comment: it does not even send the request to the server and goes straight to .catch(err) and says it is Network Error. Nothing really special to work with..

Comment: Have you added the necessary permissions into the android manifest file for network access?

Comment: android.permission.INTERNET was already included. don't know what other permissions I need.

Comment: yeah if you have set everything up then i have no idea :/

Comment: I see..I really appreciate you were trying to help me tho :)

Comment: np, i guess you are sure you have net access on android :D

Comment: @ckim16 did you find the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Set header to

```
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  },
```